# Detecting a repeating integer sequence in a large python list

Tags: python, list, loops, graph, sequence

I am detecting cycles in a graph with a function I have made.

```
for repeat in xrange(1000):
    spath = bfs_spaths(edgemap, source, n, nodevals)
```

It finds the shortest cycle in the graph, from the sourcenode, based on current edgeweights (which are stored in edgemap).

Based on results, I then edit the weights in the graph, and then find a cycle again (hence the 1000 repeats).

At some point during my cycle detection, the algorithm will get stuck in a loop of detecting the same sequence of cycles.  The sequence could be, say, the same 5 cycles over and over.  Or it could be 100 different cycles over and over.  But it will, from some point onward, only repeat this sequence.

I like this behavior and I do not want to change it.  I do, however, want to detect the sequence.  I can reduce the level of complication a little bit, by storing the length of each cycle found in a list:

```
lenpath = list()
lenpath.append(len(spath))
```

Now, all we need to do is detect a repeating sequence of integers in this list.  But when the sequence begins repeating in the list is variable, as is the size of the sequence.

I have no idea how to do this.  Any recommendations?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the repeating sequence might look like in a list? Can there be duplicates in that repeating sequence?

Comment: Yes there can be.  Here is a completely random example.

[5, 3, 11, 26, 29, 58, 55, 14, 13, 13, 21, 23, 9, 16, 28, 17, 32, 14, 13, 11,  55, 14, 13, 13, 21, 23, 9, 16, 28, 17, 32, 14, 13, 11,  55, 14, 13, 13, 21, 23, 9, 16, 28, 17, 32, 14, 13, 11,  55, 14, 13, 13, 21, 23, 9, 16, 28, 17, 32, 14, 13, 11.....]

Comment: I can understanding if it is necessary to put limitations on duplicates or duplicate subsequences(e.g. 13,12,14,15 in: 5,7,9,13,12,14,15,13,12,14,15,5,7,9,13,12,14,15,13,12,14,15,5,7,9,13,12,14,15,13,12,14,15), as well as limitations on the size of a potential sequence.  I imagine both of those constraints are probably necessary.

Comment: What you want to do is design a loop that iterates through the elements. Once it hits an element, it starts going forward to scans for repetitions of that. Once it hits a repetition, it checks if the next character is also a repetition, and so on. This iteration continues until you hit the end of the list. Such a test could be accomplished by recursion, maybe.

Comment: Sorry if that doesn't make sense lol.